# How to use multiple inputs for a multiclass classification problem using an SVM

Tags: scikit-learn, svm

I'm following along the guide on this website:
https://towardsdatascience.com/machine-learning-nlp-text-classification-using-scikit-learn-python-and-nltk-c52b92a7c73a

And I managed to make it work for my current problem, now onto my actual question. In this guide, they are only using one input/feature, I'm wondering if anyone has any experience in making this multi-input (so providing 2 different inputs each of which are their own strings of text), or perhaps a text input and a continuous input? Would this be possible?

I saw a different approach using the SVC() function where you vectorize your text input, and then you concatenate your continuous input onto that array, but I'm not sure if this is 100% correct as this actually decreased my accuracy.

Thank you in advance

Comment: You have an example on scikit-learn with two classes: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html